# Capture user input in SSH

Tags: ssh, python, keyboard

Say you are at work, you ssh to your home PC and opened a python `game.py`. No VNC. Is it possible to press down and up, space, etc. inside the window of the game? No need to see the actual game graphics, I'm just prototyping something, just want to be able to send inputs to the game using ssh.

The task should require nothing more than SSH because I'm connecting with android.

Comment: Is that `game.py` a X11 application? What X server is it connecting to? See `xdotool` to send key events to a X windows.  Or is it a terminal application?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it's a pyglet game, not cli, i don't know what xserver is connecting to right now

Comment: The X server it's connecting to would be the one where it's displayed on. If you run the ssh client in a X Window terminal emulator with the -X or -Y option. Then, `$DISPLAY` on the remote machine will point to sshd's proxy connection to your X server and your game will be displayed here, not there (and you could send keyboard events from here). If you don't use -X or -Y, then that game.py won't be aware of any X server to connect to so should fail.